# How can I overlay a Lottie animation on top of a page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, lottie

Currently I using Xamarin Forms 5 (preview) and targeting Android 8.1 with the latest Lottie installed (3.5.0 for XF and 4.0.8 for Android)

I'm wanting to add some seasonal themes to my app and was looking to "overlay" a Lottie animation on top of the pages. Currently I use Lottie for a splash screen and it works great, but I cant work out how to apply something app wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `InputTransparent="True"` basically means the control does not intercept the user input. Therefore any control under it will work as expected.